# Trying to press a button on an internet page using vba

Tags: vba, excel, web

I know there is a similar question to this - but it doesn't show enough detail to help me, I am still new to this and need a little more guidance. What I am trying to do is use a VBA Macro to press a button on a web page.

The details that I can find out about the button are

```
class = "urBtnEmph"
id = "b1_pki"
ct= "Button"
onclick  = "LoginViaPKI();"
```

It isn't a page I have written, or have access to change anything on. But is there anyway I can automate clicking the button?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with IE:

```
   Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = IE.document
'below line may be needed in case the page load is slow    
'Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop 

    Dim Button As Object
        Set Button = doc.getElementById("b1_pki")
        Button.Click
```

It requires reference to Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Thanks Angel - IE is the browser I'm using, and when I use the line

Set Button = doc.getElementById("b1_pki")

I am getting the error of "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Any ideas?

Comment: I've missed one line, which is now added in above code. If still problems, could you provide a link to give it a try.

Comment: Hi, I'm still getting issues,

It doesn't seem to like the New InternetExplorer, I tried changing it to object. It also doesn't seem to like the HTMLDocument. I'm getting a little lost with this now, I'm not really sure what Dim's I should be trying to create

Comment: Hi, I think I have figured it out, I didn't have the Microsoft HTML Object Library and the Microsoft Internet Controls turned on.

Thanks

Comment: I am happy to hear you solved it :) Thanks for posting back! Will update my answer with the other reference for future readers ;)